# add a dynamic text base on data-town to the first of an element(s)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I got some li items that have unique data-town. each time checkbox clicked items added to a modal.

I want to add a text for similar town one time to the top of the first of these similar item.

this is my code so far:

```js
$('.ad-item__info--add-to-modal').click(function () {
          if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest('.ad-item').addClass("ad-item--add-to-modal");
          } else {
            $(this).closest('.ad-item').removeClass("ad-item--add-to-modal");
          }
        });


//add items to modal
        const $modalList = $('.en-ads-modal__list');
        const $checkboxes = $('.ad-item__info--add-to-modal').on('change', e => {
          let modalContent = $checkboxes.filter(':checked').map((i, cb) => $(cb).closest('.ad-item').clone()).get();
          $modalList.html(modalContent);

 if ($('.ad-item__info--add-to-modal').is(':checked')) {

            var htmlForLATown = `
                <li class="pdf-before-item">
                  <p>___LA____</p>
                </li>
              `;
            $(".en-ads-modal__list .ad-item--add-to-modal[data-town='70']:first").before(htmlForLATown);

            var htmlForRomeTown = `
                <li class="pdf-before-item">
                  <p>___Rome____</p>
                </li>
              `;
            $(".en-ads-modal__list .ad-item--add-to-modal[data-town='73']:first").before(htmlForRomeTown);

            var htmlForLondonTown = `
                <li class="pdf-before-item">
                  <p>___London____</p>
                </li>
              `;
            $(".en-ads-modal__list .ad-item--add-to-modal[data-town='72']:first").before(htmlForLondonTown);

            var htmlForTehranTown = `
                <li class="pdf-before-item">
                  <p>___Tehran____</p>
                </li>
              `;
            $(".en-ads-modal__list .ad-item--add-to-modal[data-town='72']:first").before(htmlForTehranTown);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="wrapper__list">
<li class="ad-item" data-town="70">item 1
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">LA</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
<li class="ad-item" data-town="73">item 2
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">Rome</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
<li class="ad-item" data-town="70">item 3
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">LA</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
<li class="ad-item" data-town="72">item 4
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">London</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
<li class="ad-item" data-town="71">item 5
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">Tehran</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
<li class="ad-item" data-town="72">item 6
<p class="ad-item__info--item-town">London</p>
  <label class="ad-item__info--item ad-item__info--item-label">
    <input type="checkbox" class="ad-item__info--add-to-modal">
  add to modal</label>
</li>
</ul>

<ul class="en-ads-modal__list"></ul>
```

now my code is not fully dynamic base on add this text to first item(s) and I must coded for every town.

Another thing is for example if user clicked on first LA checkbox and then Rome checkbox and then checked second LA it's not going below the first LA.